# Populating a mutableArray suddenly stopped working when building device changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This code used to work fine last week and the only thing that changed since is the device used (the previous one was iPad mini on ios9.1, current one is an iPad mini running iOS 8.4)

```
self.minutesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    [self.minutesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

now I always get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {2147483647, 1}
>   exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'

I tried to find where the error was from using breakpoints and the only thing I can say for sure is that the for loop is running fine until the last call (when `i = 9`)

FWIW, I'm using Xcode 7.

Comment: How have you created self.minutesArray in your .h? Also, does inserting it as a string into the array make any difference?

Comment: You could try making it a local variable rather than global to see if that changes anything? NSMutableArray testArray* = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: IF minutesArray is not weak ;) the code is fine. - in that case try cleaning the target, deleting Xcode's derived data and/or rebooting

Comment: The bug is not in the code shown.  The exception is referring to an instance of `NSMutableIndexSet`, which you do not use here.

Comment: @Avi But I don't use NSMutableIndexSet, my guess was that the method [aMutableArray addObject:anObject] call the method of NSMutalbeIndexSet but correct me if i'm wrong ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan well, it was not weak but wasn't strong either! (never understood these..) but putting it strong doesn't change anything..

Comment: @JoeBenton yes i did but doesn't work either way.. and i also tried with a local valuable (minArr) but doesn't work.

Comment: @JulienDeblock Strong is the default so my statement was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Avi says. The error is not in the code that you are posting.

Set an exception breakpoint in Xcode, then check where the error actually happens.

Comment: The comment I posted earlier
     
"@Avi But I don't use NSMutableIndexSet, my guess was that the method [aMutableArray addObject:anObject] call the method of NSMutalbeIndexSet but correct me if i'm wrong ;) – Julien Deblock 17 hours ago" and the end of my original post : "I tried to find where the error was from using breakpoints and the only thing I can say for sure is that the for loop is running fine until the last call (when i = 9)"

Comment: My bad you were totally right! Well, either ways i don't use explicitly this method but the error was coming from a piece of code use below, hence the loop running fine until the last call ;)